# GoogleAuthIOException using Blogger V3 API on android

Tags: android

I try to adapt task-android-sample for blogger but it returns this error :

> Logcat
>   04-23 13:28:21.949: W/System.err(2286): com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
>   04-23 13:28:21.969: W/System.err(2286):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:286)
>   04-23 13:28:21.969: W/System.err(2286):     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)

In the console.developers.google.com I activate BloggerV3 and create an OAuth credential for android application with the package name of my app and the good sha1.

What is wrong ?
Thank you

Here is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final Level LOGGING_LEVEL = Level.OFF;
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
GoogleAccountCredential credential;

final HttpTransport httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
final JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 0;
static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1;
static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 2; 
Blogger blogger;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Logger.getLogger("com.google.api.client").setLevel(LOGGING_LEVEL);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    credential =
            GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(BloggerScopes.BLOGGER));//"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger"));

    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null)); 

    // Tasks client
    blogger =
        new com.google.api.services.blogger.Blogger.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("MyBlogger/1.0").build(); 


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}


  @Override
  protected void onResume() {    
    super.onResume();
    if (checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
      haveGooglePlayServices();
    }
  } 


  void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(final int connectionStatusCode) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            Dialog dialog =
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode, MainActivity.this,
                    REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
            dialog.show();
          }
        });
      } 

  /** Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date. */
  private boolean checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    final int connectionStatusCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
      showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }



  private void haveGooglePlayServices() {
    // check if there is already an account selected
    if (credential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
      // ask user to choose account
      chooseAccount();
    } else {
      // blogger post
        BloggerTest();
    }

  }

  private void BloggerTest() {
        Post npost = new Post();
        npost.setContent("coucou");
        npost.setTitle("title");
        (new AsyncLoadInsertPost(this)).execute(npost);
  }

  public class AsyncLoadInsertPost extends AsyncTask<Post, Void, Post> {

        // Store the context passed to the AsyncTask when the system instantiates it.
        Context localContext;

        // Constructor called by the system to instantiate the task
        public AsyncLoadInsertPost(Context context) {
            // Required by the semantics of AsyncTask
            super();
            // Set a Context for the background task
            localContext = context;

        }

        @Override
        protected Post doInBackground(Post... params) {
            Post post = null;
            Post npost = params[0];
            try {
                Insert postsInsertAction = blogger.posts().insert("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", npost)
                .setIsDraft(true);
                post = postsInsertAction.execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return post;
        }


    }


  private void chooseAccount() {     
    startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

after many tests, it works. Maybe it's because I add an email address in the consent screen from the Google developer console. Maybe it's because I enable Tasks.API or because I create a new project on the Google developer console